# How does Caffe's convolution really work?

Tags: performance, gpu, convolution, pycaffe

So I was playing around with pycaffe's convolution function implemented as part of a basic convolution layer. Here's my `convolution.prototxt` file:

```
name: "convolution"
input: "data"
input_dim: 1
input_dim: 1
input_dim: 227
input_dim: 227

layer {
  name: "conv"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 96
    kernel_size: 11
    stride: 1
  }
}
```

Those parameters are the same as that of the AlexNet's first CONV layer (except the stride, which is actually 4).

I have a Macbook Pro with an NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M 1024 MB GPU. I'm not sure it means much, but my laptop also has an Intel HD 4000 as a built-in GPU.

I did a few tests on my laptop while varying the stride hyperparameter, first on GPU mode and then CPU.

1) Varying strides after calling `caffe.set_device(0); caffe.set_mode_gpu()`:

```
Stride 1: 27.26 ms
Stride 2: 14.27 ms
Stride 3: 10.57 ms
Stride 4: 7.45 ms
```

2) Varying strides after calling `caffe.set_mode_cpu()`:

```
Stride 1: 49.77 ms # expected
Stride 2: 9.92 ms # this and the results after this don't make sense
Stride 3: 4.50 ms
Stride 4: 1.96 ms
```

*(mean of 3.)*

I'm just trying to understand how Caffe's convolution works based on these tests. Can anyone help me shed light on this?  Why does CPU mode execute faster than GPU mode?

---

Test code I used if you're interested in seeing for yourself:

```
import numpy as np
import caffe
import time

caffe.set_device(0)
caffe.set_mode_gpu() # caffe.set_mode_cpu()

net = caffe.Net('convolution.prototxt', caffe.TEST)
total = 0.0
for _ in range(3):
    net.blobs['data'].data[...] = np.random.randn(1, 1, 227, 227) # there really is an ellipsis there
    net.params['conv'][0].data[...] = np.random.randn(96, 1, 11, 11)
    s = time.time()
    r = net.forward()
    e = time.time()
    total += (e - s)

print total / 3 * 1000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after digging around, I found out that Caffe basically uses extra memory to flatten out local regions, and then uses level3 BLAS routines (cblas_sgemm in particular) to carry out matrix multiplication to get the result. This results in speedy computation at the cost of extra memory.

References can be found [here](https://petewarden.com/2015/04/20/why-gemm-is-at-the-heart-of-deep-learning/) and [here](https://yunmingzhang.wordpress.com/2015/03/13/how-does-3d-convolution-really-works-in-caffe-a-detailed-analysis/).

Memory operations with GPUs is, in general, much costlier than for CPUs. All the extra memory usage could be a possible explanation for the slowdown encountered when running in GPU mode. This would also depend on the GPU's specs itself.